# Meaning that is displayed by [alternatives --config mta] is what?

Tags: linux, unix, configuration, mta

The following screen appears when run [alternatives --config mta].

```
There are 2 programs which provide 'mta'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
 + 1           /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
*  2           /usr/sbin/sendmail.sendmail

Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number:
```

1. What does asterisk(*) mean?
2. What does plus(+) mean?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The asterisk (`*) indicates the option that the alternatives software believes is "best" and would use if auto mode is selected.

Comment: It is incredible, IMO, that this information is not in the man page.

Comment: What's more incredible is how everybody seemingly forgot to address what the plus (`+`) means.

Answer (score 0):

In `alternatives`, each link has a priority which you set when you use `alternatives --install` or it is set automatically for you. The priority is used to choose the link when `alternatives` is in auto mode.

The asterisk indicates the link with the highest priority.